# How to debug Unknown field error in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, metrics

This might be rookie question. I am not well versed with kubernetes. I added this to my `deployment.yaml`

```
ad.datadoghq.com/helm-chart.check_names: |
          ["openmetrics"]
ad.datadoghq.com/helm-chart.init_configs: |
          [{}]
ad.datadoghq.com/helm-chart.instances: |
          [
            {
              "prometheus_url": "http://%%host%%:7071/metrics",
              "namespace": "custom-metrics",
              "metrics": [ "jvm*" ]
            }
          ]
```

But I get this error

```
error validating data: [ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.metadata): unknown field "ad.datadoghq.com/helm-chart.check_names" in io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.ObjectMeta, ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.metadata)
```

What does this error mean? Does it mean that I need to define `ad.datadoghq.com/helm-chart.check_names` somewhere? If so, where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably adding this in a wrong place - according to your error messages - you're adding this to `Deployment.spec.template.metadata`

you can check [official helm deployment template](https://github.com/DataDog/helm-charts/blob/959c136e87599d0a6ce6f09031677745511d0d08/charts/datadog-operator/templates/deployment.yaml#L29) and [this example on documentation](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitoring-kubernetes-with-datadog/#deploy-the-cluster-agent) - values such `ad.datadoghq.com/helm-chart.check_names` are annotations, so these needs to be defined under path `Deployment.spec.template.metadata.annotations`

> **annotations**: a map of string keys and values that can be used by
> external tooling to store and retrieve arbitrary metadata about this
> object
> (see [the annotations docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/annotations/))

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: datadog-cluster-agent
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: datadog-cluster-agent
  template:
    metadata: # <- not directly under 'metadata'
      labels:
        app: datadog-cluster-agent
      name: datadog-agent
      annotations: # <- add here
        ad.datadoghq.com/datadog-cluster-agent.check_names: '["prometheus"]'
        ad.datadoghq.com/datadog-cluster-agent.init_configs: '[{}]'
        ad.datadoghq.com/datadog-cluster-agent.instances: '[{"prometheus_url": "http://%%host%%:5000/metrics","namespace": "datadog.cluster_agent","metrics": ["go_goroutines","go_memstats_*","process_*","api_requests","datadog_requests","external_metrics", "cluster_checks_*"]}]'
    spec:
```